# Java Date is randomly showing wrong time

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a simple XPage that is doing a partial refresh every 30 second for the demo purpose.
And randomly `new Date()` is returning a date that is one hour wrong.
But if I do

```
var d=session.createDateTime(new Date())
d.setNow()
```

it will return the correct datetime allways.

I've also tried printing everything on the console and the result is the same.
A database showing the problem can be found here 
http://l.bitcasa.com/gco-V3cq

Anybody know what could cause this ?

[image]

Comment: Can't access database. That looks like it needs a PMR/SPR.

Comment: Stange I can download the file using the link above. I'll create a PMR when I have tested the problem on 9.0.1 also

Comment: Did you try to use SimpleDateFormat to render the JavaDate. The problem could be in Java.Date or in the formatter. Time zone - DST would be a main suspect

Comment: I tried to print TimeZone and DST and that didn't change when the problem occurred. The problem seams to be fixed in 9.0.1 but not in 9.0 but I'm not 100% sure yet. Will update here when I know.